# What is the marginal variance of the mean of $y$ if I only know the variance of the conditional mean of $y$?

Tags: regression, variance, prediction, conditional-expectation

Suppose an estimate for the conditional mean of $y$ given $x$ is $\hat{E}(y|x)$. Suppose the variance (or the variance estimate) of $\hat{E}(y|x)$ is known to be $V(\hat{E}(y|x))$ for all $x$.

The population mean of $y$ is $E(y)=E_x[E(y|x)]$. An estimator for $E(y)$ is therefore $\hat{E}(y)=E_N[\hat{E}(y|x)]$ where $E_N$ means sample mean across $N$ observations.

Is there a way to derive $V(\hat{E}(y))$ from our knowledge of $V(\hat{E}(y|x))$? It is not simply $E_N[V(\hat{E}(y|x))]$ or is it?

The background are model-based estimates for $\hat{E}(y|x)$ and $V(\hat{E}(y|x))$, as in regression. In my problem I have a model which gives me both quantities but I am interested in inference on $E(y)$ which requires $V(\hat{E}(y))$. Analytically I cannot derive this estimator, but since I know the variances of the conditional mean estimates, I wonder if I can pool them in some way to derive the variance of the mean of $y$.

Comment: If you wanna do inference on the unconditional mean of y and you observe y, why work with regression? the estimate of Ey is just sample average with very well known variance etc. It seems to me you are overcomplicating given what you say you want.

Comment: @JesperHybel A justified question. I tried to simplify my problem description perhaps a bit too much. What I did not say is that some $y$ in the sample are not observed, but the $x$ are observed for all units. The distribution of $x$ for the cases where $y$ is observed is different from the distribution where $y$ is not observed. The idea is to use the information in $x$ to make inference about the mean of $y$ for all units, including those for which $y$ is not observed. In principle this is a regression estimator for missing data analysis. Does this make sense?

Comment: I guess, so you have sample 1: $y_i,x_i$ for $i=1,...,N_1$ and then sample 2: $x_{N_1+j}$ for $j=1,...,N_2$ and want to estimate $\mathbb E[y]$ taking sample 2 into account?

Comment: @JesperHybel Yes that's it, and in sample 2 the distribution of $x$ is different, and only the samples taken jointly represent a fully random sample from the population with respect to $y$ and $x$.

Comment: The model you need will depend why y is unobserved for sample 2. An example is the Tobit model used for wage modelling, where you only observe wage for people who have work but also observe x for those who do not work. So there is no ONE answer independent of your modelling decisions which will be justifiable only given context specific knowledge.

Comment: @JesperHybel We assume $\hat{E}(y|x)$ is correctly specified in both samples (the model estimated from sample one may be used in sample 2). This assumption is called missing at random. Perhaps I should change the question to include these considerations but they are not key to what I am asking.

Comment: Well then maybe make discrete model for sample belongingness $p(x)$ probability of being in sample 1 and used $E[y] = E[y\lvert x,sample=1] p(x) + E[y\lvert x,sample=2](1-p(x))$. Still my point was simply that you probably need to model why $y$ is unobserved, hence the belongingness to sample. I don't have more specific ideas sorry. But are you assuming that $\mathbb E[y\lvert x, sample]=\mathbb E[y\lvert x]$? So the only difference between the sample are coming from covariates so to speak?